# Manage display at entity reference field Drupal

Tags: datetime

I have created two content types **A** and **B**.I have a date field in **A** which is referred in **B**. But in **B** I want to display the date field separately.

i.e 3 Different select list for month, year and day.

Comment: Question: do you want to ENTER the date in content type B through a day, month and year select lists, or do you want to DISPLAY the date separating day, month and year?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create different display modes to be used in the different contexts that this entity's date field is being displayed.

Create a display mode for each different way you want it displayed with either of these possible methods:

- Modules that let you create and customize view modes through the UI:

  - https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode
  - https://www.drupal.org/project/ds
- Custom code

  - https://www.drupal.org/node/1577752 & https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7

The entity_view_mode module is the simplest approach, as display suite (ds) has many more features and options.

Once you create the view modes, then you can select the mode to be used for the entityreference field when the entity is being rendered there.